# displaying a power point presentation through a grails application

Tags: grails, powerpoint

I'm working on a grails application and being asked if it's possible to display a viewable embedded powerpoint. Someone said, I should take each slide and make an image and display it that way. Anyone know of a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/). Upload the PowerPoint to SlideShare and click "Embed" to generate an `iframe` element that can be embedded in your GSP.